# How to Selectively Adjust the Position of the Footnote Mark in a Chapter Title

Tags: vertical-alignment, footnotes, chapters, titles, vertical

Consider the code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage{perpage}
\MakePerPage{footnote} %the perpage package command
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}

\usepackage{moresize}
\usepackage{tgpagella} % Sets tgpagella as main font.

\begin{document}
\chapter*{INTRODUCTION.\footnote{A footnote whose mark I would like to be able to raise a little.}}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\end{document}
```

which produces the title

[image]

QUESTION: How may I selectively adjust (in this case, raise) the vertical position of the footnote mark which is included in this particular title? I think the current position of the mark is affected by either the use of  `\usepackage{moresize}` or the particular font `tgpagella` I have chosen. But in any case, I would like to know how to do this on a case-by-case basis, as I recall having encountered this anomaly in the past.

Thank you.

Comment: From the duplicate: `\chapter*{INTRODUCTION.\raisebox{5pt}{\footnotemark}\footnotetext{A footnote whose mark I would like to be able to raise a little.}}` raises the symbol while keeping the footnote.